# How to convert a fraction to a floating point?

Tags: floating-point, computer-science

Lets suppose I have 0.128 or 0.008. The fraction cannot be represented in binary fixed point, so I don't know how to find out the mantissa in order to convert it to a floating point.

Lets suppose i have int 100, a floating point binary string will be:
01000010110010000000000000000000.
I want to do the same for 0.128 , but i dont know to to round the fraction,because i need this for the manttissa.

Comment: those are already floating points. Do you want to convert from floating point to a fraction?

Comment: why is the `assembly` tag relevant here?

Comment: @RedAlert : I want to Convert it to a binary represination.

Comment: @J... becuase its basic to understand assembly and how it works

Comment: @Anton then which assembly language are you using?  There are a lot of them, and they can be wildly different from one another.  Do you have anything you've tried?  If yes, can you post that code?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sensible assemblers out there accept floating point literals and treat them accordingly. Why are you trying to do this by hand?

Comment: @Anton what do you mean "convert it to binary"? Everything on your machine is already implicitly converted to binary, it's how CPUs work.

Comment: @RedAlert I meant that i want it in 32 bit binary representation.

Comment: @Anton floats are already stored in 32 bit binary. Do you want to convert a float to a binary string?

Comment: a fraction has the form a/b, not a.b

Comment: @RedAlert Yes,i want to have a binary string.
i mean,what's the mantissa of 0.128 or 0.008 represented by a IEEE floating point  binary string.

Comment: @Anton Which language are you using? There are libraries out there that can do this for you, or you can look up how CPUs handle floating point numbers and do the conversion yourself.

Comment: @RedAlert You dont understand me!!!
Lets suppose i have int 100, a floating point binary string will be:
01000010110010000000000000000000.
I want to do the same for 0.128 , but i dont know to to round the fraction,because i need this for the manttissa.

Comment: @KenWhite i edited the question,is thar clear now?

Comment: Yes, that's much more clear regarding what you're asking. Thanks. :-)

Comment: If you have the character string "0.128", drop the decimal point and convert to integer 128, then divide by 1000.

Comment: @HotLicks he needs the binary representation of the number, the division by 1000 should be done in base 2.

Comment: @1010 - How do you *not* do division in base 2, without resorting to some sort of decimal arithmetic library?

Comment: he's trying to do it by hand, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert to binary the fractional part of a decimal number, you can multiply succesively the fractional part by 2. Each product will produce a 0 or a 1 in the integer part, which will be each digit of the binary representation (in order from left to right).

You can continue multiplying until the fractional part is 0, or until you obtain the number of digits needed (and then truncate or round).

Note that only the fractional numbers that are sum of negative powers of two will have an exact representation. You'll find that decimal numbers with a few digits are periodic in base 2.

From your examples the binary representation of 0.008 will start with 0.00000010...

```
0.008 x 2 = 0.016  First fractional digit is 0
0.016 x 2 = 0.032
0.032 x 2 = 0.064
0.064 x 2 = 0.128
0.128 x 2 = 0.256
0.256 x 2 = 0.512
0.512 x 2 = 1.024  First one
0.024 x 2 = 0.048
...
```

Note that multiplying by 2 in base two is equivalent to a shift to the left, or to move the dot to the right one digit, hence moving to the integer part the first fractional digit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this float to bit [converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) it should help you to understand how it works.

Example:

Target number 3.75

1. Convert it to the powers of 2 (integral part is sum of positive powers and fractional is sum of negative powers)

   5.75 = 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 + 1*2^(-1) + 1*2^(-2)
   or in binary form

   101.11
2. Normalize mantisa, all numbers should start with 1

   1.0111*e^2